# Medical imaging - image quality?

Tags: medical-device, medical-imaging

Are there any resources or literature that spell out the factors affecting image quality for each of the main imaging techniques or can someone provide such a list?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some resources and books you can use but before that check out [FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/RadiationEmittingProductsandProcedures/MedicalImaging/default.htm) ,[radiologyeducation.com](http://www.radiologyeducation.com/), [virginia.edu](https://www.med-ed.virginia.edu/courses/rad/) , [emory.edu](http://www.emory.edu/X-RAYS/Guide/ICQF.htm) and [sprawls.org](http://www.sprawls.org/ppmi2/IMGCHAR/) i think they can pretty much give you the information you want.

For fundamental information and physic of radiography ( which i think is the answer to your question) :

[Principles of Radiographic Imaging: An Art and a Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401871941)

[Review of Radiologic Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0781785693)

[The Essential Physics of Medical Imaging](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-Physics-Medical-Imaging/dp/0781780578)

[Fundamentals of Medical Imaging](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521519152)
[Principles Radiographic Imaging Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439058725)

[Radiology Fundamentals](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461409441)

[Radiobiology for the Radiologist](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1608311937)

For MRI i recommend :

[MRI in Practice](https://www.amazon.co.uk/MRI-Practice-Catherine-Westbrook/dp/1444337432)

For PET scan :

[Basics of PET Imaging: Physics, Chemistry, and Regulations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441908048)

CT scan :

[Computed Tomography for Technologists](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0781777518)

[Step by Step Ct Scan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904798810)

[Fundamentals of Body Ct](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416000305)

If you need other sources you can see [bookdepository](https://www.bookdepository.com/category/1384/Medical-Imaging) and [amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/lm/R2HHXT9A0744MB) I hope that i helped.

Comment: Thank you for this. 'Review of Radiologic Physics' is just what I am after.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. but you were not very specific in your question if you make it a little more specific maybe i be able to give you a more suitable answer as you know the physic and the technic behind every method of imaging differ from one to another

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the goal in medical imaging is to be effective at making a determination about various disease states.  So generating a "quality" image means a different thing, depending upon the target.

One may wish to examine the effectiveness of various imaging modalities when targeting a specific disease.  In the following figure, for medullary thyroid cancer, we see that the effectiveness (sensitivity) varies with the modality and the place in the body where the target might reside:

[image: percent effectiveness for medullary thyroid cancer]

(the figure above comes from [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-6694/14/15/3643))

Again, a question about "image quality" would benefit by expanding more about what that means. For instance, you might have very fine-grained and high resolution imaging of non-diseased artifacts, but the imaging modality is not capable of differentiating target (disease) from normal tissue.  The image might be considered "high quality" on the basis of resolution, but "low quality" on the basis of disease detection.